# Getting Child Windows Handles

Tags: winapi

Currently there are several ways to get a ChildWindow handle; FindWindowEx (uses parent handle, plus window caption), GetWindow (uses parent handle, and Z-Order), and EnumChildWindows. None are satisfactory for my application.

Would like to use something like FindWindowEx, but this requires knowledge of the contents of the TextBox (caption) that's used by FindWindowsEx. This works if the TextBox contents is static, but in most cases the contents change and and would be unknown to the Application trying to find the TextBox handle.

Does anyone know of a Win32 API that would function like FindWindowEX, using the Parent Handle, but instead of the ChildWindow caption, looks for a user specified TAG property for the ChildWindow that would remain static?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdlgctrlid

Comment: EnumChildWindows is the most general: It gives you all the child windows, and then you can pick the one you like.

Comment: Of course, at some point, somebody is going to have to assign IDs to the controls. Did you do that?

Answer (score 1):

The [`GetDlgItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdlgitem) function accepts the parent window handle and child item ID.

It is not limited to dialog boxes despite the name.

> You can use the GetDlgItem function with any parent-child window pair, not just with dialog boxes.

Comment: For the VB6 TextBox I don't see any "ID" property. Is the Child Item "ID" property your referring to the TAG, or the actual name of the control, or something else? Curiously, "GetDlgItem" is not referred to in Dan Appleman's book VB Programmer's guide to the Win32 API"

Comment: Just noticed the property "Index", this must be the property, as "ID" is of Integer type; would you agree?

Comment: Another possible issue, is GetDlgItem only found in the C++/MFC; as stated I'm using VB6.

Comment: @Xytsrm: `GetDlgItem` is in Win32 since the Win16->Win32 transition, in user32.dll (which you would have known if you checked the link).  You can call it from VB.  VB properties are not visible in the Win32 API.  Are you writing the code for the window whose TextBox you are looking for?  Then you can just use the `HWnd` VB property.  You can also set the child item ID with a different WinAPI function -- `SetWindowLong(textbox1.hWnd, GWL_ID, nID);`

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I'm actually trying to access a textbox in one application, from another application. And currently using a combination of FindWindow to get the parent hWin, and then use GetWindow to get the TextBox handle. While it works fine; GetWindow is limited to Z-Order, And FindWindowEx has other issues. With the additional information you provided regarding the ID I should be able to Declare GetDlGItem and SetWindowLong to function together. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, the "Tag property" you're referring to is not a SetProp property, but rather a VB6 custom control property. Those are not part of the Win32 API surface. Maybe the app is kind enough to assign an AutomationID via UI Automation. (Though since this is VB6, odds aren't very good.) You can modify the VB6 app to do something that identifies the window more precisely (say, by doing a SetProp to say "This is the one you're looking for!")

Comment: @RaymondChen: I think `SetWindowLong(GWL_ID)` is the best way to place a permanent identity on a control, because that's how "pure" WinAPI GUI windows do it.  And then you don't have to go searching for the matching window, because `GetDlgItem` already is aware of this form of identity.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, the ID is more well-known, but there is the risk that the ID is being used for something already. (Some people are "creative" and put, say, their "this" pointer in the ID. That's why it's a 64-bit value.) A uniquely-named property is not going to cause any trouble.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Sure, but it's OP's VB program so he owns `GWL_ID` (and also `GWLP_USERDATA` etc.)

Comment: @BenVoigt I wouldn't put it past VB to use the GWL_ID for something devious.

Comment: Guy's thanks for all the input.  The combination of GetDlgItem & SetWindowLong worked very well.